# Habilitar reporte de errores de cualquier tipo – PHP

Tags: php, nginx

He intentado colocar las siguientes piezas en mi código PHP:

- `error_reporting(E_ALL)`
- `ini_set('error_reporting', 1);`

Definitivamente no hay solución. Lo que simplemente quiero es mostrar, literalmente, **cualquier** tipo de error ya sea su nivel/grado de importancia como noticia, aviso, error, etc.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?
He intentado todo y he revisado un montón de preguntas similares en la comunidad de **Stackoverflow**, pero ninguna me ha funcionado.

Estoy utilizando PHP 7.0 en un servidor web Nginx.

Tengo acceso SSH y SFTP total.

Gracias por sus respuestas,

// Jose Antonio

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @JoseAntonio te sugiero revises lo que comenta gbianchi, es importante para que sepas el funcionamiento básico del sitio y tu respuesta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 0):

**error_reporting(E_ALL);** es con punto y coma, quizas eso te falto ya que con esa linea de codigo visualizas todos los errores, no es necesario que pongas las 2 lineas de codigo, solo con una basta tambien puedes utilizar
**error_reporting(-1);** que funciona de manera bastante parecida o tambien puedes usar **ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);**.

Te recomiendo visitar y leer el manual de php para mas informacion respecto a errores en [php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php).

Tambien puedes probar con esto:

try {
   // Codigo que debiera tener errores...
} catch (ArithmeticError | Exception $e) {
   // compila
}

Comment: Estimado, no funciona.

Comment: Puedes subir una imagen con los errores, o tu código para obtener mas información respecto a porque no funciona la linea de código.

Comment: No hay ningun error visible, si son avisos o noticias el script continua y no los muestra, si es un error da como resultado una página vacía, blanca.

Answer (score 0):

Para versiones PHP <= 5.4

```
ini_set('display_errors', '-1');
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)
```

Para versiones PHP > 5.4

```
ini_set('display_errors', '-1');
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**display_errors**

> Nota :
>
> Aunque display_errors puede ser establecido en tiempo de ejecución
>   (con ini_set()), **no tendrá ningún efecto si el script tiene errores
>   fatales.** Esto es debido a que la acción deseada en tiempo de ejecución
>   no se ejecuta.

Es decir cuando se produce un error fatal la unica forma de visualizarlo es en el archivo del log.

La ruta del fichero donde se almacena el log de errores viene dado por la directiva `error_log`.

Puedes encontrar una lista de las directivas de error [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php).